# Can more than one biztalk Management Groups be created for same Biztalk server?

Tags: biztalk

I want to create two Biztalk management groups within the same Biztalk server 2006R2.

When I open the Biztalk Server Configuration console, I found that all buttons are disabled, seems that I cannot create another Biztalk databases for another Biztalk Group on the same Biztalk server.

Do I misunderstand something on the Biztalk configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559010.aspx)

> While BizTalk Server groups may contain multiple BizTalk Server
>   computers, any given BizTalk Server computer may only be associated
>   with a single BizTalk Server group.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for specifically cannot be done.

BizTalk Administrator can be used to manage multiple Groups but a partucular computer can only be joined to one BizTalk Group.